# Role in user is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

When I do `_userManager.FindByNameAsync(email)` I am able to retrieve the correct user record. However, my roles field has a count of 0. If I look in the db, there is in fact roles associated to my user's id.

I am on .NET 2.0

In my startup.cs:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>
```

My applicationRole :

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    // public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; } = new List<ApplicationUser>();

    public ApplicationRole(){}
    public ApplicationRole(string roleName) : base(roleName) {}
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole<string>> Users { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<IdentityRoleClaim<string>> Claims { get; set; }
}
```

My applicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual Player Player { get; set; }

    public List<ApplicationUserClubs> Clubs { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerProfileId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Navigation property for the roles this user belongs to.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole<string>> Roles { get; } = new List<IdentityUserRole<string>>();
}
```

My query is:

```
ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
```

This used to work fine before my migration over to .NET 2.0

EDIT:

```
foreach (IdentityRole role in allRoles)
{
    bool isUserInRole = role.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == u.Id) != null;
    userInRoles.Add(item: new AdminUserRoleViewModel
    {
        Id = role.Id,
        Name = role.Name,
        IsUserInRole = isUserInRole
    });
}
```

I get an exception when I try to do Role.Users. The exception says:

> 'IdentityRole' does not contain a definition for 'Users' and no
>   extension method 'Users' accepting a first argument of type
>   'IdentityRole' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?

That's when I decided to extend IdentityRole with my custom class ApplicationRole

Also here is my context File:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers")
        .HasKey(x => x.Id);

    builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles")
        .HasKey(x => x.Id);

    builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("AspNetUserRoles")
        .HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });

    builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims")
        .HasKey(x => x.Id);

    builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("AspNetUserLogins")
        .HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.ProviderKey });

    builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().ToTable("AspNetUserTokens")
        .HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.LoginProvider, x.Name });

    builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>().ToTable("AspNetRoleClaims")
        .HasKey(x => x.Id);

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUserToken>().ToTable("UserTokens")
    .HasKey(x => x.Id);
}
```

Comment: where's your query ? hard to guess with this.

Comment: My query is just:
`ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);`

Comment: I mean, can you show us the linq query behind that _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email) ?

Comment: I'm not sure what it might be. It's predefined by Identity I believe. It's 
`public virtual Task<TUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName);` which is in the `UserManager` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`

Comment: Have you gone through the setup in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x

Comment: I have only gone through: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-2.1
and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-2.1. But not the one you linked me to. I'll check it out now. thanks

Comment: So I changed my startup.cs so it's like the link you sent me. However, this puts me back to the reason why I had to extend IdentityRole. The `role.users` did not exist.

Comment: Do you have `lazyLoading` enabled or disabled?

Comment: Is there an option for that? I was under the assumption lazyLoading wasn't implemented for ef 7

Comment: Have you tried `ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.Include(u = > u.Roles).FindByNameAsync(model.Email);` ?

Comment: I did, but ApplicationUser does not have `Include` implemented

Comment: Make sure that you have  `using System.Data.Entity;`

Comment: Ok I'll try that when I get to work. Thanks! So do we have to do that everywhere we originally used the userManager? Have you tried core 2.1 yet btw?

Comment: @BerndLinde Is that part of .Net Core 1.1? It seems to be falling back to 4.6.1 for some reason.

Comment: It is part of the EF Core library, more info can be seen here [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Comment: @BerndLinde It turns out I didn't need the lazy loading... My actual issue is that `userManage.GetRolesAsync` doesnt get any roles. Am I supposed to delete all my migrations file from .NET core 1.1 before doing a migration in .NET core 2.0