# Can .net core 1 app multi target .net45?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is it possible to set a target fallback of net45 in the csproj file of a NET Core 1 project?

```
<PackageTargetFallback>
    $(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wpa81+wp8
</PackageTargetFallback >
```

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

I also tried this without success:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp1.1; net45</TargetFrameworks>
```

EDIT:
I'm using Visual Studio Code
-I just fixed my typo. I had typed  as singular, but in my csproj file it was actually plural. Thank you though guys!

Comment: If you want to specify multiple frameworks in that last tag there, you need to use the plural version, `<TargetFrameworks>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To target multiple frameworks you need to use the tag **TargetFrameworks**.

This

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1; net45</TargetFramework>
```

Should be

```
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp1.1; net45</TargetFrameworks>
```

Comment: Hey Thanks Marcus, It was a typo on my end. I did have it as <TargetFrameworks></TargetFrameworks>. The weird thing is, when I do this, i have packages complaining that they don't support net45 but only netcoreapp1.1

Comment: @user6728767 ok. But that is not wierd at all. net45 and core is different frameworks and build differently

Comment: Oh okay sorry for the dumb question Marcus. I'm new to the .NET environment and have been thrown into the deep end. Previous developer left. Everything in the app is running perfectly fine with netcoreapp1.1. However, I wanted to add another package that needs net45. Is there a way I can keep everything the way it currently is, but also run the package under net45?

Comment: @user6728767 Np, some packages work in multiple framework but some don't but it's not strange if it don't work becasue usually you build your package against a specific framework. Often you can find a .core version of an .net packages, try look for that.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the .core version, but it seems to be forked from the original. The title mentions that its .core 1.0. However, I have no clue how to install or include it in my project. It doesn't seem to be in the nugget manager so I can't use that to install it.

Here's the link:
https://github.com/geeklearningio/PushSharp-Core

Thanks so much for helping me. I've been stuck on this for nearly 2 weeks. I've tried migrating our existing app to .NET Core 2, but with my limited knowledge on .NET, I went down a rabbit hole.

Comment: @user6728767 if you look at the PushSharp.nuspec file in the github repo, you can se that it targeting dlls build on lib\net45. It's not core.

Comment: Oh that's true hmm. I wonder why they titled it `.NET Core 1.0`. I'm checking their commit logs and it looks like they have individual commits per module within the library. Like for the apple one they have a `PushSharp Apple migration` commit. I don't quite understand what they did, but at the very bottom of the link they have this project.json file they added. Would this allow me to use it?
https://github.com/geeklearningio/PushSharp-Core/commit/5e5ad048d8f18e7a342f18de15920c64706bbaf5

Comment: @user6728767 you can allways download specific commits and use them. But, its not recommended to use it before it's in the master. An option might be to create a separete project which targets net45. Consume this packages and create your own integration with your core project.

Comment: I think that specific commit I linked you to has already been merged into master. Did it look like it could support core? (Again I apologize if this is a dumb question).  Also if it did support it, how would I include it in my project? Would It be under the `<ItemGroup>` and have the `<PackageReferece>` include the path?

Comment: @user6728767 You download it via nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/PushSharp/4.0.10

Comment: That's the original version that I was trying to use multiple framework targets to use. However, It didn't work. So I tried looking for a .core version, which looks like this one might support:
https://github.com/geeklearningio/PushSharp-Core
However, I don't think its in nuget.

The nuget link you provided is for this one: https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp

Comment: @user6728767 Looks like they released version supported for core 2.0 https://www.nuget.org/packages/PushSharp.Core/1.0.0

Comment: Ahh it looks like you're right. The owner of that nuget package is one of the members of the geeklearningio repro. So it looks like my only option is to continue trying to figure out my core 1 to core2 migration =(, or make a wrapper around the .net45 one?

There's no way to use the core1.0 from that github repro itself though right?

Comment: @user6728767 I think the best option is to upgrade to core 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I really appreciate it. I marked you as the answer. If you have time, maybe you can take a look at my other question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49786671/role-in-user-is-empty

I got stuck in my migration, which was why i attempted to find an alternative by using the library as part of a multiple framework target.